# Predicting nucleotide sequence efficiency

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new to machine learning and I am wondering whether it would be possible to use my available biological data for clustering. I want to find out whether a group of DNA sequences can be clustered into two groups, efficient and not efficient.

I have five sets, each containing about 480 short sequences (lets call them samples). Each set is having an effect with different strength:

Set1 - Very good effect

Set2 - Good effect

Set3 - Minor effect

Set4 - Very minor effect

Set5 - No effect

Each sample has some features, e.g. free energy,starting with a specific nucleotide...

Now my question is whether I can find out which type of sample in my sets are playing a role for the effect of the whole set. My only assumption is that in set1 I have more efficient samples then in set5 (either none or very few). A very simple (not realistic) result could be, all samples which start with nucleotide 'A' end end with nucleotide 'C' are causing the effect.

Is it possible to use machine learning to find out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That definitely sounds like a problem where machine learning could give good results. I recommend that you look into [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/), a powerful and easy to use toolkit for machine learning in Python. There are many introductory examples and tutorials available.

For your use case, I would say that random forests could give good results, although it's hard to say without knowing more about the structure of the data. They are available in the class [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) in sklearn. Again, there are many tutorials and examples to be found.

---

Since your training data is unlabeled, you may want to look into unsupervised learning methods. A simple class of such methods are clustering algorithms. In sklearn, you can find, for instance, [k-means clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) along other such algorithms. The idea would be to let the algorithm split your data into different cluster and see if there is any correlation between cluster membership and observed effect.

Comment: Is it possible to use random forest without to label the data? I don't know which of the 480 samples are efficient or not, I know only the result of the group of both. The structure is something like [sample, [feature1,feature2,feature3]], for example [[sequence1, [free energy, start_letter, end_letter]], [sequence2, [free energy, start_letter, end_letter]] same for the rest 478 sequences and this 5 time for each set.

Comment: @snowflake: I didn't realize at first that your data is essentially unlabelled. I added a paragraph on unsupervised learning methods, in particular clustering.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will have a look. One more thing which is not clear for me, can I treat all sets as one set or should I keep them separate?

Comment: @snowflake: for unsupervised learning, I would at first merge them into one large dataset and see if the algorithm uncovers any obvious structure which might relate to the effects you're seeing.

Comment: OK and is it possible to find out what describes two clusters? If I have three features and lets say only two of them are important. Do I get a feedback which features combination splits cluster one and two? Sorry, for those dumb questions...

Comment: @snowflake: how exactly the clusters are described depends on the algorithm. For k-means in particular, the clusters are simply those elements closest to a particular midpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your description what the 5 sets (what sound like labels) correspond to, but I will assume that you are essentially asking about feature learning: you would like to know which features to choose to best predict what set a given sequence is from. Determining this from scratch is an open problem in machine learning and there are many possible approaches depending on the particulars of your situation.

You can select a set of features (just by making logical guesses) and calculate them for all sequences, then perform [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) on all the vectors you have generated. PCA will give you the linear combination of features that accounts for the most variability in your data which is useful in designing meaningful features.

Comment: It's a bit confusing. I have 5 sets with 480 unlabeled samples each. The samples cluster into two groups, positive and negative. I don't know the group of a single sample, I only know the effect of the whole set. If the effect is strong, I assume that there are many positive samples inside this set, if the effect is weak, I assume that mostly negative samples are inside the set. I can assume that all samples in set 5 are negative, because there is no effect. Basically I could label them with negatives. Would this be helpful?